# How do I move my Tiny Tower from one device to another?

Tags: tiny-tower

I recently bought a new phone. Is there a way to move my Tiny Tower to my new phone?

Comment: Last time I played was over a year ago, but last I checked your tower is synced by your email so just login and your tower should be restored!

Comment: Confirmed, just installed it on my new phone never played in over a year, signed in with my email and my tower was here.

Comment: At least with Android, your saved game is stored on the Mobage servers so logging into Mobage will restore your tower. I play the same tower across different devices this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiny Tower data is sync'd with your email or Facebook account or Mobage account. All data remains on the Mobage server, so just login on the new device and all your Tower data will be there.

Thanks to @Emerica and @Charles Caldwell for testing it out.